# Products and Coproducts - Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

We know that initial objects in a category $C$ are final objects in the opposite category $C^{op}$ obtained by 'reversing all arrows'.

Now, given a category $C$ and objects $A,B$ of it, the product of $A$and $B$ is final object of the category $C_{A,B}$, where objects are morphisms from objects of $C$, $Z$. to $A$ and $B$, and morphisms are commutative diagrams between them. Similarly, the coproduct is the initial object in $C^{A,B}$, obtained by taking as objects the morphisms from $A$ and $B$ to $Z$ in $Obj(C)$, and morphisms as commutative diagrams.

Now, it is clear to me that products are not always also coproducts. The category Set is a trivial example.

However, isn't $C^{A,B}$ the opposite category of $C_{A,B}$? In that case, doesn't my first sentence suggest otherwise? Where am I wrong?

Comment: No, $C^{A,B}$ is not the opposite category of $C_{A,B}$: the morphisms in $C^{A,B}$ are pairs $(f,g)$ of morphisms in $C$, with $f,g$ having the same codomain, $f$ having domain $A$, and $g$ having domain $C$. The morphisms in the opposite category if $C_{A,B}$ are pairs $(f,g)$ where $f$ and $g$ are morphisms in $C$ that have a common domain in $C$, with codomain of $f$ in $C$ being $A$ and the codomain of $g$ in $C$ being $B$, but thinking of the arrows as pointing the "other way". This is not the same as a pair $(f,g)$ as described for $C^{A,B}$.

Comment: Ah I get it! In this case, $C^{op}$ is the category with morphisms such that a single arrow in the commutative diagram is reversed.

Comment: No. The point is that the arrows in $C^{op}$ are the arrows of $C$ itself, but if the arrow goes from $X$ to $Y$ in $C$ then we *say* it goes from $Y$ to $X$ in $C^{op}$.